# Flutter difference between Shared Preferences and Global Configuration

Tags: flutter, sharedpreferences

I could not really figure out the difference between the Shared Preferences (https://pub.dev/packages/shared_preferences) and the Global Configuration (https://pub.dev/packages/global_configuration) in Flutter.

Can anyone help me with that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Global Configurations gives you more options on how to store the info on the device or package with the app as well as being able to load the info remotely via a URL.

If you are looking for a robust on-device storage solution, I suggest you check out Hive https://pub.dev/packages/hive